# How do I use migrations to create a postgres sequence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How do I use migrations to create a postgres sequence?

I have created a migrations file with the following executes:

```
execute 'CREATE SEQUENCE "ServiceAvailability_ID_seq";'
execute <<-SQL
  ALTER TABLE "ServiceAvailability" 
    ALTER COLUMN "ID" set DEFAULT NEXTVAL("ServiceAvailability_ID_seq")
SQL
```

However, when running rake db:migrate I'm getting the following error:

> PGError: ERROR:  column "ServiceAvailability_ID_seq" does not exist
>   :       ALTER TABLE "ServiceAvailability" 
>           ALTER COLUMN "ID" set DEFAULT NEXTVAL("ServiceAvailability_ID_seq")

Second question, rake db:schema:dump is meant to create a file that can be portably used against any DB, however, on investigating a schema:dump it appears to only include table, field and field type information and misses out indexes and sequences?

Comment: Why are you manually creating sequences anyways? When rails creates the `id` column it types it as `serial`, which creates an implicit sequence. And rails should read indexes just fine.

Comment: No rails doesn't types the id column as serial but as integer and applies a sequence. [Postgresql official][1] doc explains that it is the same. For instance : *CREATE TABLE nom_de_table (
    nom_de_colonne SERIAL*
); is same as *CREATE SEQUENCE nom_de_table_nom_de_colonne_seq;
CREATE TABLE nom_de_table (
    nom_de_colonne integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('nom_de_table_nom_de_colonne_seq') NOT NULL
);
ALTER SEQUENCE nom_de_table_nom_de_colonne_seq OWNED BY nom_de_table.nom_de_colonne;* [1]: http://docs.postgresqlfr.org/9.1/datatype.html#datatype-numeric

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
    execute 'CREATE SEQUENCE ServiceAvailability_ID_seq;'
execute <<-SQL
  ALTER TABLE "ServiceAvailability" 
    ALTER COLUMN "ID" set DEFAULT NEXTVAL('ServiceAvailability_ID_seq');
SQL
```

Comment: To get this to work for me, I had to remove the double quotes where they appear.

Answer (score -4):

Actually you should not use migrations like that, in future if you change your db to MySQL or any other db(rails supported) you will face problems. Please check the Ruby on Rails guides on the link given below.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html

Comment: This is already a Postgres-specific request due to the use of sequences.